# If $x^2 - 10ax - 11b = 0$ has roots $c$ and $d$ and $x^2 - 10cx - 11d = 0$ has roots $a$ and $b$, then find $a + b + c + d$?

Tags: polynomials, roots, vieta-jumping

If $x^2 - 10ax - 11b = 0$ have roots $c$ and $d$ and $x^2 - 10cx - 11d = 0$ have roots $a$ and $b$, then find $a + b + c + d$?

My attempt-

[Using Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we get

$$ c+d=10a, a+b=10c $$

Because sum of roots $=\frac{-b}{a}$

Also using Vieta's formula we get

$$ cd=-11b, ab=-11d $$

Because product of roots $=\frac{c}{a}$

So now we need to solve these equations-

$$ c+d=10a, a+b=10c, cd=-11b, ab=-11d $$

So I solved it like this-

In the above line let each 4 equation be eq $1,2,3,4$.

Dividing eq $1$ by $2$ and cancelled $10$ in RHS because its both in numerator and denominator,

$$ \frac{c+d}{a+b}=\frac{a}{c} $$

Using [componendo alone](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/) we get

$$ \frac{c+d+a+b}{a+b}=\frac{a+c}{c} $$

Putting all the values using eq $1$ and $2$,

$$ \frac{10a+10c}{ac}=\frac{a+c}{c} $$

Solving this we get $a=10$

Now doing mischiefs(some changes) with eq $1$,

$$d=10a-c  =>d=100-c  $$

Let the above equation be equation $5$.

Similarly doing some mischiefs with equation $2$ also

$$ b=10c-10 $$

Let above equation be equation $6$.

Now using equation $4$,

$$ ab=-11d $$

We know $a=10$ and using equation $5$ and $6$.

$$ 10(10c-10)=-11(100-c) $$

$$ 100c-100=-1100+11c $$

$$ 89c+1000=0 $$

$$ c=\frac{-1000}{89} $$

Now see adding equation $1$ and $2$

$$a+b+c+d=10a+10c$$

Thus we need to only find now $10(a+c)$.

$$ 10(a+c) $$

$$ 10(10+\frac{-1000}{89}) $$

But wait this is the wrong answer according to my book. What have I done wrong?

Here is the correct solution according to a website-

https://www.sarthaks.com/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=286792613098888701

Please help me with this question. Apologies for asking a homework question. Apologies for something missing in the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. Your title tells us nothing about the subject of the question,  it's a useless title.

Comment: You seem to be dividing by expressions but you don't know if they are not zero. Also the linked solution does the same thing (dividing by $c-a$), maybe some assumptions are missing in the problem statement? In current formulation, we could satisfy the conditions with $a=b=c=d=0$, which is probably not what was intented.

Comment: @jjagmath is the title now fine?

Comment: @JitendraSingh componendo alone (or whatever you call it) part is wrong

Comment: You made a mistake after "Putting all the values using eq 1 and 2,..."

Comment: The question have 3 possible answers: $0$, $-220$ and $1210$.

Comment: Sorry for not telling you the full question. The full question was a+b is not equal to 0 was also given

Comment: @Sil $a+c$ is not 0 (given in question) thus dividing the expression holds sense

Comment: @Snowball and how can you say that? Let a fraction be $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ Add 1 to both sides and you get $ \frac{a+b}{b}=\frac{c+d}{d}$ So how can you say compendo part is wrong

Comment: @JitendraSingh where do you get $a+b = ac$, it should be $a+b = 10c$ and that division does not give you anything new.

Comment: @Snowball ya that where I got wrong thanks for showing interest in my question

Comment: @Snowball I have accepted your answer but write your latest comment in the answer pls

Comment: Mathjax writing hint: To number an equation, type something like `y = x^2 \tag{12}` to get $$y = x^2 \tag{12}$$.

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks for the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach, after doing componendo alone, you substitute $a+b = ac$, which should $10c$ and it shouldn't give you anything new. Instead, we can do as follows which is straightforward calculation.

$d = 10 a - c$ and $b = 10c - a$

$(ab)(cd) = (-11b)(-11d) = 121bd$

If $b=0$, then $d = 0 = a = c$ and same for $d = 0$, $a=0$ and $c=0$ cases

Otherwise, $ac = 121$

$ab = 10ac - a^2 = -11d = -110a + 11 c$

$a^2 -110a +11\frac{121}{a} - 1210 = 0$

$a^3 - 10*11a^2 - 10*11^2a + 11^3 = 0$

$(a^3+11^3) - 110a(a + 11) = 0$

$(a+11)(a^2 - 121a + 11^2) = 0$

$a$ has 3 solutions and find solution set for each case ($c = \dfrac{121}{a}$, $d = 10 a - c$ and $b = 10c - a$).

Comment: Sorry for not telling you the full question. The full question was a+b is not equal to 0 was also given

Comment: @JitendraSingh anyways, you can get 4 different solution set. If $a+b \neq 0$ then you are left with 3 solution set which can be found by solving last cubic equation.